# Pure CSS - Read more/Read Less images

Tags: html, css, hide, show, show-hide

In my search for a neat, nice and working "Read more / Read Less"-function I managed to find below code. This code works fine and can be used several times on the same page (what I really need).

This piece of code have one backslash. I need to also show/hide several images which this code will hide *BUT* the "Show more/less"-button will move according to the size of the image which is really not what I need.

I cannot see how to modify this code so it can hide images as well.

The problem can be seen in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrtxqu94/16/

**CSS**

```
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />
<div class="read-more-wrap">
  What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
  specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
  with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <span class="read-more-target">Why do we use it?
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" height="auto" width="250px" />

<p>Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</span></div>
<label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
```

---

**CSS Solution**

Thanks to Logiwan, setting the image height to `0` and `auto` will make the image work as the text.

```
 .read-more-target img {
  height: 0;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target img {
  height: auto;
}
```

Complete code:

```
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-target img {
  height: 0;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target img {
  height: auto;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to use the same idea for the height of all images inside the `.read-more-target`.

Something like this:

```
.read-more-target img {
  height: 0;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target img {
  height: auto;
}
```

Here is an edit to your fiddle that does this: https://jsfiddle.net/xrtxqu94/20/

Answer (score 2):

event if the container of the images are set to `opacity:0` , the images will still occupy space in the document flow.

here is a solution, you can add the following rules :

```
.read-more-state ~ .read-more-wrap img {
     display: none;
}

 .read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap img {
     display: block;
}
```

this will ensure that the image takes no space when the read-more state is closed

https://jsfiddle.net/xrtxqu94/26/

Comment: Probably makes more sense to use height rather than `display: none` since with `display: none` the image instantaneously pops in and out of existence. With height the nice transition value is used.

Comment: This one is also working and work as intended but I would like to keep the nice transition. Thank you for your answer.