# Read more/less button for multiple content

Tags: css, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been trying to display several sheets thanks to the more/less button with pure CSS based on [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/xrtxqu94/20/), one of the solution suggested for [Pure CSS - Read more/Read Less images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849643/pure-css-read-more-read-less-images). I have no problem displaying the first sheet. But for the others, it doesn't work. Each time I click on the "read more" button, only the first sheet appears. I guess that I need to change the `id` `input` ref. As you will see `<xsl:for-each select="./@xml:id">` is a different sheet.

This is a `xsl` section:

```
<xsl:template match="Name of the template">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <xsl:if test="count(./key('whatAction-subCat', @xml:id)) != 0">
                <li>
                    <!-- some data -->
                    <br />
                    <xsl:call-template name="whatResult"/>
                </li>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="whatResult">
        <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="result" />
        <div class="read-more-wrap">
            <xsl:text>Read</xsl:text>
            <span class="read-more-target">
                <table class="table-2">
                    <caption>What Result</caption>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Occur. in</th>
                        <th>What Role</th>
                        <th>What Context</th>
                        <th>What Sphere</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./@xml:id">
                        <!-- verb competition -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="contend"/>
                        <!-- verb motion -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="self_motion"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="arriving"/>
                        <!-- etc -->
                        ...
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </span>
        </div>
        <label for="result" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
    </xsl:template>
```

A few print screen for a better understanding: [show less btn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ceagjknvudye0jv/show_less.png?dl=0), [show more btn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyuzri9jjqxigjl/show_more.png?dl=0), and [show more of several btn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t84n3s4zhbud3u7/show_more_mutl.png?dl=0).
As you will see, another concern is the space between the hidden content and the more button. I need to look to the CSS--one step at a time...

In advance, thanks so very much for your help!

Vanessa

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:
My main concern is to display a long list of data at the request of a user. Thus, I choose the modal solution based on this [example](https://github.com/ireade/demo.bitsofco.de/blob/gh-pages/the-target-trick/modal.html). In order to avoid the display of the same sheet, I added the modal solution to each `<xsl:template name="A NAME>`.

````
<!-- I call the templates where I add the modal solution -->
 <xsl:template match="category[@corresp]">    
   <xsl:for-each select="./@xml:id">
      <!--to display content in each sub-category, ex. 'contend', 'self_motion' -->    
         <xsl:if test=".!contains(., 'contend') and  //ref[@corresp='#contend'] ">
             <xsl:call-template name="contend"/>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test=".!contains(., 'self_motion') and  //ref[@corresp='#self_motion'] ">
             <xsl:call-template name="self_motion"/>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- some templates of data with the modal solution -->```
 <xsl:template name="contend">
    <div id="contend">
    </div>
    <a href="#modal-container-contend" aria-label="Open Navigation">
        <xsl:text>Read the detailed structural unit for this sub-category</xsl:text>
    </a>
    <div id="modal-container-contend">
        <div class="modal">
            <table class="table-2">
                <caption>What Result</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Occur. in</th>
                    <th>What Role</th>
                    <th>What Context</th>
                    <th>What Sphere</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">What Behavior</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each
                    select="//ref[@corresp = '#contend']/ancestor::node()/../following-sibling::ref[@n = '2']">
                    <xsl:call-template name="following-subCatVerb"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
            <a href="#contend" aria-label="Close Modal">close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="self_motion">
    <div id="self_motion">
    </div> 
    <a href="#modal-container-self-motion" aria-label="Open Navigation">
        <xsl:text>Read the detailed structural unit for this sub-category</xsl:text>
    </a>
    <div id="modal-container-self-motion">
        <div class="modal">
            <table class="table-2">
                <caption>What Result</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Occur. in</th>
                    <th>What Role</th>
                    <th>What Context</th>
                    <th>What Sphere</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">What Behavior</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each
                    select="//ref[@corresp = '#self_motion']/ancestor::node()/../following-sibling::ref[@n = '2']">
                    <xsl:call-template name="following-subCatVerb"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
            <a href="#self_motion" aria-label="Close Modal">close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- the same logic for same sheets of data-->
````

And the CSS for the modal solution:

```
#modal-container-contend, 
#modal-container-self-motion,
#modal-container-arriving,
#modal-container-satisfying {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex;}

.modal {width: 70%; background: #fff; padding: 20px; text-align: center;}

#modal-container-contend:not(:target), 
#modal-container-self-motion:not(:target),
#modal-container-arriving:not(:target),
#modal-container-satisfying:not(:target) {opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;}

#modal-container-contend:target, 
#modal-container-self-motion:target,
#modal-container-arriving:target,
#modal-container-satisfying:target {opacity: 1; visibility: visible; transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;}
```